# How to create a generic function which will accept all types/sizes of structures and then fill the members accordingly

Tags: c, struct

I want to create a generic function which will accept the address of a structure one at a time(there will be plenty of differrent structures to be passed to this function) and a sql query along with that. This function will then run the query, store the result set, and fill the members of the structure one by one with this result set depending upon whose address is passed in the function.

Any help is much appreciated thanks..

Comment: Not possible. C provides no means to detect type of struct at runtime. You need to pass type information manually and fill members manually for each different struct type.

Answer (score 1):

C is a statically typed language, that means that it must know the type of variables at compile time. So you can't do that